# Die Verwendung vom Verlauf der Gegenwart

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Ich war gestern mit einer Freundin in Santa Cruz, Läden ***ansehend***.

Ich frage mich, ob ich das auch so schreiben kann, was die Bedeutung des Satzes nicht ändern soll:

> Ich war gestern mit einer Freundin in Santa Cruz, ***ansehend*** Läden.

Welche Sätze machen Sinn? Und warum?

Comment: Keinen der beiden Sätze würde man sagen.

Comment: Der zweite ist falscher als der erste.

Comment: Wenn es nicht darum ging, einen Laden zu mieten, sondern das Angebot anzugucken, würde ich *Läden* durch *Schaufenster* ersetzen.

Comment: Im ersten Satz einfach das _d_ vor dem Punkt weglassen, evtl. auch das Komma oder Perfekt: _Ich **habe mir** gestern mit einer Freundin in Santa Cruz Läden **angesehen**_.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich hat noch niemand den Titel korrigiert, weil er irgendwie poetisch anmutet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wie bereits in den Kommentaren angesprochen, sind beide Sätze hölzern oder sogar falsch.

Während der erste Satz grammatikalisch noch halbwegs sinnvoll ist, ist der zweite definitiv falsch.

Die Verlaufsform existiert im Deutschen so nicht. Um eine Verlaufsform zu bilden, wird eine Hilfskonstruktion aus einer Form von *sein* + *am* + substantiviertem Infinitiv benötigt. Zum Beispiel:

> - Ich bin am Aufräumen
> - Sie sind bereits am Aufbrechen

Die Form *ansehend* in deinem Beispiel ist keine Verlaufsform, sondern ein aktivisches Partizip (Partizip I). Die Form ist korrekt, wird aber in der Regel eher zusammen mit Substantiven verwendet:

> - spielende Kinder
> - fliegende Vögel
> - rauchende Kamine

Undekliniert kann es auch nach dem Substantiv stehen und wird dem Prädikat untergeordnet:

> Das Kind lag **schreiend** im Wagen

Die Form *ansehend* wird sehr selten verwendet und klingt sperrig. Mir fällt kein Satz ein, in dem diese Form gebräuchlich klingt und der nicht zumindest einen untergeordneten Nebensatz beinhaltet.

Für das, was du ausdrücken möchtest, eignet sich eine simple *um* + Infinitiv-Konstruktion besser:

> Ich war gestern mit meiner Freundin in Santa Cruz, **um** Läden **anzusehen**.

Dadurch wird ein kausaler Zusammenhang ausgedrückt (keine Verlaufsform). Wenn ein Vorkommen beschrieben werden soll, das zur Zeit des Laden-Ansehens eintrat, lässt sich dies mit *während* + untergeordnetem Nebensatz ausdrücken:

> **Während** ich mit meiner Freundin in Santa Cruz Läden **ansah**, traf ich auf meinen Schulfreund Carl.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort, und willkommen beim StackExchange der deutschen Sprache. Wenn du magst, kannst du dir die [tour] ansehen, oder einen Blick ins [help] werfen. Viel Spaß :-)

Comment: Dankeschön. :-)

Comment: Inzwischen hast Du auch genügend magische Einhornpunkte für die aktive Teilnahme am [chat]. Schau doch mal vorbei.

Comment: Vielleicht weniger schön, aber durchaus in Gebrauch wäre einfach „Läden ansehen“ statt „um Läden anzusehen“. Inhaltlich ist es sogar genauer, denn letzteres lässt die Möglichkeit offen, dass der Versuch gescheitert ist.

Comment: Speziell in diesem Fall gibt es auch den schönen (vielleicht etwas norddeutsch gefärbten) Begriff "einen Schaufensterbummel zu machen". Das beschreibt genau den Vorgang, durch die Stadt zu gehen und sich Läden anzusehen, ohne wirklich etwas kaufen zu wollen.

Comment: Der Infinitiv im _am_-Progressiv ist nicht substantiviert und sollte daher auch nicht groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: @Crissov Doch, ist er. Die entsprechende Regel ist im Grammatik-Duden (Ausgabe 2005) unter "Verlaufsform", Regel 594 zu finden. Zitat: *„Bei sein + substantiviertem Infinitiv mit am (ich bin am Überlegen) […] handelt es sich um eine Verlaufsform (Progressivkonstruktion), die mit der englischen Progressivform […] zu vergleichen, […] jedoch nicht voll grammatikalisiert ist.“*

Comment: Hier der aktuellere (aber unveränderte) Eintrag auf der Duden-Website: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/am#Bedeutung3

Comment: Im Eisenberg-Duden, ernsthaft? Ich bin enttäuscht. Ändert aber nichts daran, dass es Quatsch ist (und von anderen Germanisten anders gesehen wird). Dieses _am_ ist genausowenig Präposition wie _zu_, wenn es mit Infinitiv steht, oder _am_ mit Superlativ. Ein Substantiv in einer Verbform würde ja auch gar keinen Sinn machen. In stärker dialektalen Formen wird das noch deutlicher, z.B. _ich war die Läden anamsehen_. Egal, alles weitere gehört eher in eine eigene Frage, die es noch nicht zu geben scheint.

Comment: Ich bin kein Germanist, aber rein vom Sprachgefühl her ergibt eine Großschreibung Sinn. Alles andere wäre eher verwirrend. Da die Wendung aber sowieso als umgangssprachlich gekennzeichnet ist, wäre eine Diskussion vermutlich auch müßig.

Comment: Ich gehe weiter als Carsten, und sage, die vorgeschlagene Form 'um Läden anzusehen' ist inhaltlich falsch, weil sie das Motiv nach Santa Cruz zu fahren thematisiert, und nicht die Tätigkeit dort.

Answer (score 0):

Der korrekte Ausdruck ist:

> Ich sah gestern mit einer Freundin in Santa Cruz Läden an.

In Santa Cruz gewesen zu sein, um Läden anzusehen, bringt das Motiv, nach Santa Cruz zu fahren, in den Vordergrund. Darüber wissen wir nichts. Vielleicht warst Du in Santa Cruz, um in den Zoo zu gehen, aber dann war das Wetter zu schlecht.

Offen ist noch, ob das Ansehen der Läden ein Begutachten von Ladenlokalen war, mit der Absicht, vielleicht eines zu mieten, oder ob es ein Einkaufsbummel war.

Der in Kommentaren genannte Schaufensterbummel dagegen ist typisch für das bloße Schauen durchs Schaufenster, etwa wenn die Läden geschlossen sind am Abend oder Feiertag, ohne den Laden zu betreten.

Comment: Einige benutzen das Verb "ansehen" reflexsiv. Ist das auch richtig, das Verb reflexsiv zu schreiben?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht.

Comment: „Kein Zitat“ – ist zutreffend, aber „kein Code“ stimmt erst recht. :-) Und wir benutzen `>` durchaus nicht nur für Zitate.

Comment: Wie z.B. Ich sehe mir einen Laden an. Kann man das mir weglassen, ja?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Nicht ohne Bedeutungsänderung. Etwas ansehen ist nur die Tatsache, dass man seinen Blick darauf richtet. Man könnte einen Laden ansehen, um zu beobachten, ob eine verdächtige Person diesen betritt - die Aufmerksamkeit richtet sich also nicht näher auf den Laden, sondern bloß auf die Oberfläche. Sich den Laden anzusehen heißt, die Aufmerksamkeit auf Details zu richten.